# Print variable if output is unique

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping

Hey so I in order for me to learn web scraping I'm scraping a twitter accounts tweets instead of their api and I want to print an variable IF it isn't the same as the last tweet, or last print output, this way I can just have it run every 10 minutes without spamming the same tweet.

```
post = soup.find('p', {'class':'TweetTextSize TweetTextSize--16px js-tweet-text tweet-text'}).text, new_line
```

I wanted help with something like this so if post is the same output it won't print

```
if post not post:
    print(post)
```

Comment: What did you expect `if post not post:` would do? You could write `if post is not post:` for valid syntax, but hopefully it's clear that will never evaluate truthy. Why not store previously-printed posts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Save the last post and compare the new post with the last post in a loop.

```
last_post = None
while True:
    post = soup.find('p', {'class':'TweetTextSize TweetTextSize--16px js-tweet-text tweet-text'}).text, new_line 
    if post != last_post:
        print(post)
        last_post = post
    time.sleep(600)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, I ended up making it into a function and because of that I had to global last_post after def last_tweet():